# How can I definition type of object contains generic function

Tags: typescript

```
type People = {
    getLaptop: <L>(name: string) => L
}

const makePeople = ( getPeople: People) => {
    return getPeople.getLaptop
}

const us =  {
    getLaptop: (name: string) => ({type: 'Dell'})
}

makePeople(us) //err at us
```

Version: "typescript": "^3.1.2"

The full err message look like this:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ getLaptop: (name: string) => { type: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'People'.
  Types of property 'getLaptop' are incompatible.
    Type '(name: string) => { type: string; }' is not assignable to type '<L>(name: string) => L'.
      Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'L'.
const us: {
    getLaptop: (name: string) => {
        type: string;
    };
}
```

How can I resolve this problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining what kind of type `L` is. This will not work. However you could do it like this

```
type People<L> = {
    getLaptop: (name: string) => L
}

const makePeople = ( getPeople: People<{}>) => {
    return getPeople.getLaptop
}

const us =  {
    getLaptop: (name: string) => ({type: 'Dell'})
}
```